# Access to Word Template

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having issues figuring out the best way to do this:
I have a word template for an interview pre-night. What I need to do is fill out the word template with the interviewer and the people who are interviewing them. There will always be 1 interviewee but up to 12 interviewers. The part giving me issue is that there will not always be 12 interviewers so the area that the data is moved to needs to be dynamic. Should I create a table or bookmarks in Word and use VBA to move the data, or design the report in Access? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that what you are trying to do is complicated enough that "mail merge" won't work for you.

It really depends on whether you need the end result to be a Word document or an Access report. Both easily convert to PDF for document archiving. If you prefer to work with Word, add the key fields into your document with all the formatting necessary and then use VBA to do a search replace.

Two ways you could go about dealing with the 1-12 interviewers issue:

- Use VBA to create one long segment containing all interviewers as a
  single "field".
- Add 12 sets of key fields and use search/replace
  (through VBA of course not manually) to fill in the exiting
  interviewer info and delete the key fields for the non-existing ones.